# Capture Azure VM Image with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, image, azure, capture

I have followed these steps https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/ to capture an image of a VM. Used sysprep as mentioned and I was able to replicate the VM. The problem is that when I rdp into the machine, I can't connect to SLQ Server. Login fails for Windows Authentication. Usually this means that the SQL Server is on another domain, but in this case the error is on local machine. 
So my question is, how to capture an image of a VM with SQL Server in Windows Azure and ensure that I can login with Windows Authentication at least when deployed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, I think you will need SQL Server Authentication before sysprep (I haven't tested this), as far as I know this is the same on-premises and not an Azure feature per se...

If you run sysprep on Windows, you shouldn't have any expectations that the current principals provisioned in SQL Server will continue to work. SQL Servers references Windows accounts by their SIDs and running sysprep on Windows will create a new set of SIDs for the Windows account. Therefore, you will have to re-add them to SQL Server as you've discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a solution that worked for me, in case anyone facing same problem and haven't found any working solution.

After creating an Azure VM from the Image based on a generalized VM (sysprep run):

1. Launch SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Navigate to SQL Server Services.
3. Right click on  SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)->Properties from the right side panel.
4. Select 'This account:' and enter details of current VM Administrator credentials.
5. Apply changes and restart SQL Server.

Now, try connecting to the SQL Server. It should work.